# Setting attributes in jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I have a problem with running jquery:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title></title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jQuery.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript">
       $(function(){

            $('form').attr('id','myNewId');
        });
       </script>
    </head>
    <body>

        <div align="center">
            <form id="myID">
            My Name: <input type="text" name="text"/>
            </form>

        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

no error happens , and no intellisense with netbeans..why the code doesnt work ?!?

UPDATE: now it works..

No intellisense with Netbeans..Here is my version:

```
> Product Version: NetBeans IDE 7.1.1 (Build 201203012225)
Java: 1.7.0_03; Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM 22.1-b02
System: Windows XP version 5.1 running on x86; Cp1255; en_US (nb)
User directory: C:\Documents and Settings\dddddddddddd\.netbeans\7.1.1
Cache directory: C:\Documents and Settings\dddddddddddd\.netbeans\7.1.1\var\cache
```

Comment: [**Works for me**](http://jsfiddle.net/tHTa5/) (in Chrome at least)

Comment: delete the `$(function(){` and `});` lines and try again. what happens?

Comment: yes it works as @qwertymk says.

Comment: I don't see any reason, why this shouldn't work. Also @qwertymk version is running for me. Ensure that your jQuery libary is really loaded !

Comment: how did you check the id changed or not?

Comment: ID is changed. How are you checking out if it is or not? Use Firebug or Chrome dev tools and you will verify that myNewId is set as form ID.

Comment: tpaksu nothing happens... I dont think jquery is loaded.. firebug tells me:$ is not defined

Comment: Your jQuery include is wrong.  Make sure that is correct and your code should work fine.

Comment: it doesnt work.. and i have no intellisense with netbeans

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery Intellisense is already available on Netbeans. <sup>*[[read more]](http://waynecater.wordpress.com/2011/06/25/netbeans-html5-jquery-intellisense/)*</sup>

It should work the way you are coding <sup>*[[demo]](http://jsfiddle.net/Starx/5T9L3/)*</sup>, but as of jQuery 1.6+ , you can also use [.prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) to set values for attributes<sup>*[[demo]](http://jsfiddle.net/Starx/5T9L3/1/)*</sup>

```
$('form').prop('id','myNewId');
```

---

In case jQuery is not defined, may be it is conflicting with a different jQuery version. Use this at the top of your script

```
  $.noConflict();
```

Comment: Shouldn't be .prop only used for things like selectedIndex, tagName, nodeName,... ? So to speak only for properties, and id would be an attribute.

Comment: firebug tells me: $ is not defined.. is jquery not loaded

Comment: @BlackFire27, on my demo or while you are using

Comment: @BlackFire27, It seems the script is conflicting. Check my update

Comment: It tells me that $ isnt defined on $.noConflict

Comment: @BlackFire27, ok, then `var $ = jQuery.noConflict();`

Comment: it tells me jQuery isnt defined

Comment: @BlackFire27, thats means the script hasn't been loaded then. Check the path

Comment: @EvilP, You are right, its just a workaround, I have update with proper response, Please see it.

Comment: dammit, I checked the path. I even put the file in the same directory

Comment: I have no intellisense with netbeans..why is that?

Comment: If you have placed the file in the same directory, use `<script type="text/javascript" src="jQuery.js"></script>`

Comment: i did it..now it produces no error..but the code doesnt work :(// netbeans says it is update... it is 1.7 version

Comment: @BlackFire27 Can you set up a demo I can see? Update to the latest its 7.1

Comment: I tried again. Now it works, with input tag..but not with the form tag.. I think there was a mistake in my syntax..

Comment: @BlackFire27, No it perfectly correct, see my demo for the proof. I am not sure of the cause, unless I see some test page or demo.

Comment: okay thanks.. i am trying to solve the intellisense problem..because it isnt working on my 7.1.1 version

Comment: @BlackFire27, Open a blank js document and try it. Its there my default

Comment: @BlackFire27, Type some jquery code like `$(document).`, a drop down box should pop up

Comment: The only thing that pops up, is "no suggestion"

Comment: @BlackFire27, Uninstall and do a fresh install

Answer (score 0):

Dude Its working fine for me. Make sure you jQuery.js file is located in the appropriate location and also named correctly.